# Are parents filters available to all sub modules?

Tags: angularjs

```
var x = angular.module("x", ["a","b","c"]);
x.filter('myfilter', func);
x.directive('myDirective', func);

var a = angular.module("a",[]);
a.filter('alfa', func);
a.controller('userController', func);
```

Is myFilter and myDirective also available to userController?
is alfa available to x?

Comment: Haven't tested anything, but I would expect `alfa` to be available to `x` since you've required `a`.  I would not expect `myfilter` or `myDirective` to be available to `a` as they're defined later

Comment: No "a" has no dependency on "x" (and if it did it would create a circular dependency issue).  "a" could have been written in a different javascript file and has no information about "x", but if the file that contains the definition for "a" and it's "parts" is included (via a script src) then angular would be able to find "a" in order to define "x" (since it has "a" as a dependency angular will complain if it hasn't previously seen "a" defined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Module **x** can access the filter of module **a** as it has listed it as a dependency. Module **a** however can not access the filter or directive of **x**, as there is no dependency on the module. Angular handles it for you!

Refer to: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di && http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module

The code below:

```
var x = angular.module("x", ["a"]);

x.filter('myFilter', function(){});
x.directive('myDirective', function(){})
x.controller("xCtrl", function(alfaFilter) {

})

var a = angular.module("a",[]);
a.filter('alfa', function(){} );
a.controller('userController', function(myFilterFilter) {

});
```

If you try, you'll see that DI handles alfaFilter in the first controller just fine. However, myFilterFilter will generates an error. (Despite a.filter("") being declared later than module x).

Note that the double Filter is intended, it's the way to insert filters into controllers, and was faster to demonstrate..

Comment: Think you have a caps error for x.filter('myFilter', function(){});